# Why single-char slicing on non-ASCII strings is slower?

Tags: python, string, language-lawyer, slice

Let us consider the following code:

```
n = 10000000
s1 = 'a' + 'α' * n + 'α' + 'a'
s2 = 'a' + 'a' * n + 'a' + 'a'
```

So `s1` contains non-ASCII characters, while `s2` contains strictly ASCII 7-bit characters.

---

Now, `s1` is almost twice as big as `s2`:

```
import sys


print(sys.getsizeof(s1), sys.getsizeof(s2))
# 20000080 10000052
```

If one were to perform arbitrary slicing with the same indexes on these two strings (of same length), it is not surprising that this is slower for `s1` as more data is being copied around.

What did surprise me, though, is that if one tries to get the first and last item (which are ASCII 7-bit in both), one gets (slightly) worse performance on `s1`:

```
m = 200
%timeit [s1[-1] for _ in range(m)]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 11.4 µs per loop
%timeit [s2[-1] for _ in range(m)]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop

%timeit [s1[0] for _ in range(m)]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 11 µs per loop
%timeit [s2[0] for _ in range(m)]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.89 µs per loop
```

I find the result of the last test particularly surprising because it seems to me that one could get away with an array offset in both cases, and see no reason for `s2` to be faster.

---

EDIT: to address the concerns related on timings. This is what I get for the single char slicing without `list` creation:

```
%timeit s1[-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 40.6 ns per loop
%timeit s2[-1]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ns per loop

%timeit s1[0]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 ns per loop
%timeit s2[0]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ns per loop
```

Comment: You aren't timing how long a lookup takes; you are timing how long it takes to build a new list of `str` values.

Comment: I'm finding that lookup alone (e.g. `%timeit s1[0]` vs `%timeit s2[0]`) is *faster* for `s1`, by about 3 ns. (Which is just as surprising, in some sense. But keep in mind, there are really three different "subtypes" of strings, depending on how the Unicode characters are stored internally. All-ASCII strings can use 1 bytes per character; other strings may need 2 or 4 bytes, depending on which code points exist. C-level operations may differ depending on which subtype you are dealing with.)